# How do I make my WCF Rest methods not require Content-Type when using WebInvoke

Tags: json, wcf, rest

I have a WCF REST service with an operation like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/User", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void User(User user);
```

When i call this from Fiddler, it works fine if i specify the Content-Type="application/json" like so:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:58150
Content-Length: 172
Expect: 100-continue
```

But if i exclude The Content-Type then i get an error 400 since it tries to process the request body as XML.  This is very annoying, you would REALLY THINK that setting RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json would make it so that i DO NOT have to specify the Content-Type but that is not the case.  As a matter of fact if i drop 'RequestFormat' nothing changes.  I have also tried 'wrapped' for the WebMessageBodyStyle but then the DTO comes through null.

To Clarify, this happens if i use XML in the body of the post as well (and omit the Content-Type)... so what I really want to accomplish is:

How do I make my WCF Rest methods not require Content-Type when using WebInvoke (I would expect WCF to figure it out automatically)

This is driving me crazy PLEASE help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a WebContentTypeMapper on your WebHttpBinding. In that you can tell the WCF runtime what WebContentFormat the supplied (or assumed) content type mime value supplied. Generally when a POST is received without the content-type header, this will be "application/x-www-form-urlencode" (multipart/form-data or text/plain can happen as well so be aware). Simply tell WCF that this is Json Or Xml (or whatever you need) and it will just work (your millage may vary).

```
    public class YourContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        if (contentType == "application/x-www-form-urlencode")
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Json; // assuming this is wanted
        }
        else
        {
            return WebContentFormat.Default;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply set the ContentTypeMapper to on the WebHttpBinding to an instance of your class (this can be done in config file as well on your binding with the contentTypeMapper attribute)

```
var binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.ContentTypeMapper = new YourContentTypeMapper();
```

More information => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943479(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` on your endpoint behaviour to true?

Take into consieration that this attribute is specific to NET 4.0, i remember using it to format response messages based on Accept header of http.

I haven't tried to reproduce your scenario, but reading this official documentation [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee476510.aspx) it states the following:

> If the request message contains an Accept header the Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF) infrastructure searches for a type that
>   it supports. If the Accept header specifies priorities for its media
>   types, they are honored. If no suitable format is found in the Accept
>   header, the content-type of the request message is used. **If no
>   suitable content-type is specified, the default format setting for the
>   operation is used.**

Here is the example from msdn of how automaticFormatSelectionEnabled is set.

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: thank you for your response.  Yes I do have that set but it seems to have no impact on the request - if i omit the ContentType then i get a 400 error:  The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'.